# npm run command does not use the node binary installed by nvm

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, raspberry-pi, nvm

I have install node.js using nvm on a Raspberry Pi running Raspberry Pi OS. If I run `which node`, it correctly prints the path of node binary under the `.nvm` folder. However, if I add a script in package.json

```json
 "scripts": {
    "which": "which node"
  }
```

then run `npm run which`, it prints `/usr/local/bin/node`. How could I make npm run commands use the node installed by nvm?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
nvm use //node version, you can get it: nvm ls
```